# Pass Array from MVC to javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I can pass a variable from MVC ASP.NET by using this :

```
var lastCategoryId = '<%=Model.CS.LastSelectedCategory %>';
```

This work fine with string or integer but how do I do with an array of strings? I have tried to pass the array the same way but the variable is set to System.String[] ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should do

```
var someArray=[<%foreach (var s in myStringArray){%>'<%=s%>',<%}%>];
```

Comment: you have to get rid of the last comma

Comment: @Omu: Not necessarily. Javascript parsers are very forgiving in that area. All common browsers don't mind about trailing commas in arrays.

Comment: @AdrianGrigore, Thanks for your answer..I've same problem. But I found a way for pass mvc attary in Js from your answer. but my question is like that which type of array or classes required for this type of array see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911067/how-to-access-server-side-array-clsses-or-subclasses-in-js-file-in-net-mvc

Answer (score 171):

You could let .NET handle all the heavy lifting for you with this simple line of code.

This assumes you're using MVC Razor syntax.

`var yourJavaScriptArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.YourDotNetArray));`

**For newer versions of MVC, use:**

`var yourJavaScriptArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.YourDotNetArray));`

Comment: This is so amazing! Didn't know this was supported in Razor, so darn good!

Comment: Note that `Json.Encode()` no longer works on newer versions of MVC. Use `Json.Serialize(Model.YourDotNetArray)` instead.

Answer (score 43):

You could JSON serialize it. This way could could pass even more complex values and not worry about escaping simple quotes, double quotes, etc :

```
var categoriesList = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new[] { "value1", "value2" }) %>;
```

Writing an HTML helper to do this would be even better:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static string JsonSerialize(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object value)
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(value);
    }
}
```

and then in your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var categoriesList = <%= Html.JsonSerialize(new[] { "value1", "value2" }) %>;
</script>
```

Comment: I have to admit it's a much cleaner approach than my answer. This should be voted as the solution, not my post.

Comment: @Adrian, everything is subjective. Personally I hate seeing C# in views. And I am particularly allergic to loops in views :-) Also not encoding the strings your are outputting is extremely dangerous and subject to XSS attacks. That's why I prefer to always rely on things built into the framework so that I don't have to worry about properly escaping, ...

Comment: Every time I see Darin Dimitrov answering to a question, I know I will have a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myArr = [<%=string.Join(",", strArr.Select(o => "\"" + o + "\"")) %>];
</script>
```

Comment: The problem with this one is that it doesn't wrap the string values in quotes which would cause a JavaScript error.

Comment: @Matthew Manela thanx for telling me that, fixed it

Comment: what if `o` contains a quote? What if it contains a double quote? What if it contains javascript and XSS code that could steal your authentication cookie? Can't even imagine the disasters that can be caused by writing such code.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov well, your right, that was just a simple way, probably he doesn't need encoding, who knows

Answer (score 3):

**One liner:**

```
var data = [@Html.Raw(String.Join(",", Model.MyArray.Select(i => "'" + i + "'")))];
```

Answer (score 3):

So easy, so simple

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var array = @Html.Raw(
        Json.Encode(
            (Model).Select(m=> new 
            { 
                id= m.ID, 
                name=m.Name
            })
        )
    );
</script>
```

Output is:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Name of 1"}, {"id":2,"name":"Name of 2"}, ...];
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Json.NET

```
var yourlist = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.YourList))');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to format the array into a JavaScript array syntax.

```
var someArray = [<%= Model.SomeArray.Select(x => "'" + x +"'")
                           .Aggregate((x,y) => x + ", " + y);  %>];
```

This will surround each entry by single quotes and then join them together with commas between square brackets.

Updated: removed extra parenthesis.

Comment: Sorry but I get the following exception with this solution =  ) expected

Comment: I had an extra parenthesis.  I removed it.  try now.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to provide an answer using Razor syntax:

We have a `Dictionary<int, int>` that we are rendering for a jQuery Sparkline, in the form of "an array of arrays".

```
var usageData = [ @string.Join(",", Model.UsageData.Select(d => string.Format("[{0},{1}]", d.Key, d.Value)).ToArray()) ];
```

Which is used like so:

```
$('#sparkline').UsageSparkline(usageData, { tooltipFormatter: cachedTooltips });
```

This is what we get when viewing the source:

```
var usageData = [ [-13,0],[-12,1],[-11,0],[-10,0],[-9,1],[-8,1],[-7,0],[-6,2],[-5,2],[-4,0],[-3,0],[-2,9],[-1,3],[0,4] ];
$('#sparkline').UsageSparkline(usageData, { tooltipFormatter: cachedTooltips });
```