# ASP Web Pages Razor using AJAX to return array from Database

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, asp.net-webpages

I'm working with ASP for my coursework and I am using Razor Web Pages to do an application. Now, I would like some help with retrieving information from the SQL database.

As it stands I make an ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/timetabler/Includes/ajaxModulesByUserId",
    data: { id: UserId  },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        if (data == "ERROR") {
            alert("We are unable to store the theme you have selected, therefore the change will not be permanent.");
        }
    }
});
```

This quite simply calls `ajaxModulesByUserId.cshtml` passing a userID of like 1. Now this calls the file fantastically.

Now what I'm trying to do in my CSHTML is take the requested ID, then use my C# function:

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> getAllQuery(string query)
    {
        return _db.Query(query);
    }
```

To execute my query.

Now I call it in my Razor code like this:

```
string input = "";
    input = Request["id"];
    var arr = new List<string>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        // Add new sheet to database
        using (var repo = new initDatabase("SQLServerConnectionString"))
        {
            foreach (var row in repo.getAllQuery("SELECT * FROM Module WHERE userID = " + input))
            {
                arr.Add(""+row.moduleCode+","+row.moduleTitle+"");
            }
            @session.Serialize(arr);
        }
    }
```

So I return the rows from the database and put them into an array, now my problem is, getting those values to the javascript.

As it stands I'm using a trick I read from here [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850958/pass-array-from-mvc-to-javascript), by using a function like this:

```
public static string Serialize(object o)
    {            
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return js.Serialize(o);
    }
```

This will actually let me see the values in Javascript, but I'm getting stuck as I end up with values like this:

[image: Example Output]

How can I receive a clean array? and possibly even return ALL the rows from the database as I've had to do a messy way of passing the code and title in 1 array field but separated by a comma.

Would really appreciate it if you could help me get my output correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Web Pages framework includes a [Json helper](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/160/webmatrix-working-with-the-json-helper) which can take your data and return it as JSON.

```
if (!Request["id"].IsEmpty())
{
    using (var repo = new initDatabase("SQLServerConnectionString"))
    {
        var data =  repo.getAllQuery("SELECT * FROM Module WHERE userID = @0", Request["id"])
        Json.Write(data, Response.Output);
    }
}
```