# Get string[] in razor view javascript from mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, chart.js

I'm working with Chart.js. I require -

```
labels : ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul"],
```

In my controller code I'm doing this-

```
   string[] Labels = new string[tbl.Rows.Count];
   for (int i = tbl.Rows.Count-1; i >0 ; i--)
   {
       Labels[i] = Convert.ToDateTime(tbl.Rows[i][0]).ToString("MMM") ;
   }

   Labels[0]= Convert.ToDateTime(tbl.Rows[0][0]).ToString("MMM") ;
   ViewBag.ChartLabel = Labels;
```

Everything is good till this point.

Problem arises when I want to use that value in razor page.

```
<script>
   labels : [], //How can i use ViewBag.ChartLabel here?
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most easy way to do this is to insert the values in array.

```
<script>
var labels = [];
@foreach(var label in ViewBag.ChartLabel)
{
    <text>
        labels.push('@label');
    </text>
}
</script>
```

You can find here more [ways to convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850958/pass-array-from-mvc-to-javascript), the one that I think it's the best

```
var labels = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ChartLabel));
```