# Razor - Display Dictionary Data in a PieChart using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, dictionary, pie-chart

I create a dictionary in the model, which has The City as Key and The  numbers of Kids as Value   (@Model.dictionary). I want to make the pie chart dinamically so How can I use the dicionary data instead of the static data in my drawChart function.

I hope you can help me, thanks a lot.

```
   <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


          function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['City', 'Kids per Day'],
              ['LA',    100000],
              ['NY',    100000]
            ]);

            var options = {
              title: 'Kids per City',
              is3D: true,
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a *javascript array* using razor, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23091022/3790486) that converts a `List` to arra,y you can convert from `Dictionary` very easy:

```
var array = [@Html.Raw(String.Join(",", Model.dictionary.Select(x => "['" + x.Key + "', '" + x.Value +"']")))];
```

This will create

```
[
   ['LA',    100000],
   ['NY',    100000]
]
```

And you use it like this, with few modifications.

```
function drawChart() {
    var javaScriptArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.YourDotNetArray));


    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['City', 'Kids per Day'],
      @Html.Raw(String.Join(",", Model.dictionary.Select(x => "['" + x.Key + "', '" + x.Value +"']")))
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Kids per City',
      is3D: true,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```