# How to paste C# array to javascript array in asp.net razor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, arrays, razor

Currently, I have this code for copy data from my array in C# Model to javascript array.

```
var javascriptArray = [];
@foreach (var data in Model.Array)
{
     @:javascriptArray.push(@Html.Raw(data));
}
```

but in result html I have many times

```
javasriptArray.push("string1");
javasriptArray.push("string2");
javasriptArray.push("string3");
...
```

Is there any other way to do this?

thx

Comment: use something like NewtonSoft JSON to serialize the object and print to the page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Array from MVC to javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850958/pass-array-from-mvc-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can try serializate the Array object (Newtonsoft.Json), example:

> JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Array);

Or you can print a var array in javascript:

> var myArray = ["AA","BB","CC"];