# Failing to render CanvasJS chart using ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, canvasjs

I am a beginner when it comes to the following technologies: 
- ASP.NET MVC
- Entity Framework 
- JavaScript (in this instance, CanvasJS)

I am trying to render a chart based on a Data Model that I have created in my solution. I am following the tutorial here (adapted to my own purposes) https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/integration/asp-net-mvc-charts/how-to/asp-net-mvc-charts-data-entity-database/ and I have completed the following.

- Created a Model of my data via EF
- Passed that data from my Controller to my View
- Attempted to render the chart in the View CSHTML

However, the chart does not render. When I use Chrome Debugging, the Javascript shows that the 'result' is my strongly typed model, but this must be incorrect as the error is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

The rendered Javascript is as follows:

```
<h2>StoreView - Testing this for store group P777S001</h2>
<hr />
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="text-info">Here are some examples of sales data via Entity Framework</div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="chartContainer"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var result = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[InSiteDashboard.Models.InSiteStoreSalesSummaryTable];
    var datapoints = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        datapoints.push({ label: result[i].x, y: result[i].y });
    }

    $(function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            theme: "light2",
            zoomEnabled: true,
            animationEnabled: true,
            title: { text: "Line chart" },
            data: [{
                type: "line",
                dataPoints: dataPoints,
            }]
        });
        chart.render();
    });
</script>
```

I am passing this to the View using the following code (it's prototyping so the code is messy apologies)

Controller:

```
    string _servername = $"P{store}S001";
    var sales = insite.InSiteStoreSalesSummaryTables.Where(s => s.ServerName == _servername && s.daily_sales_figure > 0);
    //var storeEntries = db.StoreSystemInformations.Where(s => s.StoreNumber == store);

    if (sales == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.TestValue = $"Testing this for store group {_servername}";
    return View(sales.ToList());
```

Can anyone see something I'm obviously doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

From first glance, I assumed your problem seem occurred because of this line:

```js
var result = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[InSiteDashboard.Models.InSiteStoreSalesSummaryTable];
```

I think you're passing list directly to a JS definition intended to create JS array, but Razor returns fully-qualified name of the `List<InSiteDashboard.Models.InSiteStoreSalesSummaryTable>` collection because Razor implicitly called `ToString()` in the view instead of iterating it.

Since ``` List``1[InSiteDashboard.Models.InSiteStoreSalesSummaryTable] ``` is not recognized as a JS identifier or property, then "*Unexpected end of input*" message was thrown because of invalid syntax.

You could use [model serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850958/pass-array-from-mvc-to-javascript) to pass `List<T>` collection as JS array, as in example below (assumed you have model directive with `@model IEnumerable<InSiteStoreSalesSummaryTable>` or `@model List<InSiteStoreSalesSummaryTable>` as implied by `return View(sales.ToList())`):

```js
// standard way
var result = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');

// using Newtonsoft.Json library
var result = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))');
```

Here is an example implementation of the script:

```
@model IEnumerable<InSiteStoreSalesSummaryTable>

<!-- other HTML elements, skipped for brevity -->

<script>
    var result = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');
    var datapoints = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        datapoints.push({ label: result[i].x, y: result[i].y });
    }

    $(function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            theme: "light2",
            zoomEnabled: true,
            animationEnabled: true,
            title: { text: "Line chart" },
            data: [{
                type: "line",
                dataPoints: dataPoints,
            }]
        });
        chart.render();
    });
</script>
```