# How can I get the Id of the particular element of each div / li / a that is created using loop in cshtml

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing a model from my controller and using a for loop to populate the model elements inside a div. For each model item there is a div having its different property. Now I want that whenever I click on any link or element in any of `divs` I must get the particular value assigned to it.

The problem I am getting is it picks up the value of only one div that was created on first iteration of the loop irrespective of the div I am using now.

Below is the simple list printed exactly as I am printing now I want the value of the link whenever I click any link created below.

Suppose there are 15 categories and I want 6th category that is "java" how do I get that using jquery.

```
@foreach (var category in ViewBag.Categories)
{
     <li class="item"><a id="categoryItem" value = @category.categoryName>@category.categoryName</a></li>

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question by including the javascript code that you have written. Try to give as much as information.

Answer (score 0):

```
id="categoryItem"
```

The problem is in this id assignment. If this is your actual code, you're just setting the same id "categoryItem" to all elements in the loop. Besides being against HTML standard, this would also cause most of the browsers to select the first element if you address an element by this id.

To fix this, you can include category name into id like this:

```
@foreach (var category in ViewBag.Categories)
{
     <li class="item"><a id="categoryItem_@category.categoryName" value ="@category.categoryName">@category.categoryName</a></li>
}
```

However, this will only work properly if your category names do not contain spaces, so using some kind of integer id instead would probably work better.

Also mind the double quotes `""` around `value` value.

Comment: Thanks for your response, But how would i implement .click and get the value in the script down below. Like i access the button by writing ```$('#id').click(function(){})``` so ```$('#what should go here?').click(function(){})```

Comment: @KunalKumar You have several options for this. First of all, you can add a `name` or `class` instead - for instance, if you write `<a id="categoryItem_@category.categoryName" value ="@category.categoryName" class="a-category-name">`, you can refer to the links as `$('.a-category-name')`. Alternatively you can pass the respective values to the on-page JS from C# as described e.g. [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12039432/625594)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `categoryId` in your `category` model? If you do then change `id="categoryItem"` to `id="@category.categoryId"`

Answer (score 0):

Given your code to build up the list:

```
@foreach (var category in ViewBag.Categories)
{
    <li class="item"><a value="@category.categoryName">@category.categoryName</a></li>
}
```

> Suppose there are 15 categories and I want 6th category that is "java" who do i get that using jquery.

This could be interpreted as:

- the 6th category, which happens to be "java" (ie the value is not relevant)

giving:

```
$("li.item>a:eq(5)").addClass("thisone");
```

or as:

- the "java" category, which happens to be the 6th one (ie the position is not relevant)

giving:

```
$("li.item>a[value=java]").addClass("thisone");
```

(which will select *all* that are "java")

or as:

- the 6th "java" category (ie there are at least 6 which are "java" and you want the 6th)

giving:

```
$("li.item>a[value=java]:eq(5)").addClass("thisone");
```

Change `.addClass("thisone")` to whatever you want to do to that item

---

You appear to be asking 3 different questions - how to get an ID, how to get nth element and:

> when I click on any link or element in any of divs I must get the particular **value** assigned to it

```
$("li.item>a").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).prop("value"))
});
```

The problem, as others have pointed out is that you likely using:

```
$("#categoryItem")...
```

and this will always give you just the first as IDs must be unique within an HTML document.  (You'll notice I removed the offending `id=` from the snippet above)